# git extensions crashes on startup

Tags: windows, git

Using git extensions 2.51.01, I sometimes get this error that when I start gitExtensions it immediately errors with:

> An entry with the same key already exists.

Even if I uninstall and re-install.  Any idea what causes this?  Here is the stack trace:

> at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource
>   resource)    at System.Collections.Generic.TreeSet`1.AddIfNotPresent(T
>   item)    at System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`2.Add(TKey
>   key, TValue value)    at
>   GitUI.GitExtensionsForm.FindWindowScreen(Point location)    at
>   GitUI.GitExtensionsForm.RestorePosition(String name)    at
>   GitUI.GitExtensionsForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
>   IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Note: I deleted this file and it seems to have fixed the issue: C:\Users\dlwiii\AppData\Local\GitExtensions\WindowPositions.xml

But not certain that this is the real solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Things you could try:

- update to the last version that is a bug fix release
- clean the "recent repositories" list
- report the issue here: https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues

Comment: In the list of recent repo, you have a 'configure this menu' and there, if I remember well it's a fight click on the list. But now that I look at the stack trace (that don't say a lot of things), I'm not sure it will solve your problem. But worth the try...

Comment: Did you find and opened an issue on the repository?

Comment: Philippe- clearing the recents assumes that I can open Git Extensions.  The whole problem is that I cannot.